# Web socket and web service with tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, websocket, apache-axis

I'm developing an app on android that communicate with server to update location information. Eg: when you find a good restaurant, you can mark in on the map and share with other people. Everyone will see it and know what special discount that restaurant is offering. I've finished the code of marking this location and share on both android and server side. I've written and deployed it as axis2 web application. Now, I want to update the location which is shared by someone in realtime. I'm thinking of web socket. But I don't know how to do with it after several days of researching. My problems are:

- I don't know which framework I should use for this case. I've tried jWebsocket, but it make me crazy because of a ton of configuration. I've tried JavaWebsocket(created by TooTallNate) and Atmosphere also, but they require running dependently. I just want to put it into the same war file with the existed code of axis2 or something that I can deploy on the tomcat server.It's very easy to find a cloud to deploy a web app, but quite difficult to run a dependent server such as JavaWebSocket, you know. Am I able to do this? Can you suggest me some framework?
- I also want to create a code at the android client side, are there any library or framework I could use?

I'm new to web socket, so I don't know where to go. Thank you for every suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [JWebSocket](http://jwebsocket.org) that based on Jetty and fully [embedable](http://jwebsocket.org/howto/ht_webapp.htm) into Tomcat. It also has different client libs (javaScript, [android](http://jwebsocket.org/downloads/dl_bundles.htm)).

Comment: Hey, can you tell me is it possible to deploy JWebSocket on the Tomcat 7? I've tried these thing:
+Tomcat 7.0.35 with jWebSocketServer-Bundle-1.0.jar, jWebSocketSamples-1.0.jar, tomcat-jwebsocket-bundle-7.0.27.jar in the libs of Tomcat
+When I restart Tomcat, I cannot access via localhost:8080 and the log said:Exception during startup
org.jwebsocket.kit.WebSocketException: XMLStreamException occurred while creating XML stream (conf/jWebSocket.xml): java.net.MalformedURLException.

Comment: Yes, its possible, see http://jwebsocket.org/howto/ht_webapp.htm (also provided in my answer)

Comment: Can you help me with this exception?

Comment: You would have to search existing answers here and if not found ask a new question on this topic.